# How can I place a text below fontelllo icon?

Tags: html, css, icons, fontello

[CHECK HERE FOR THE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiclG.jpg) I want o add text below icons, but somehow this are getting jumbled up. The current output is just the opposite of what I want. It would be nice if someone tells how to correct this error and get the icons horizontally side by side, and the text below.
................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontello';
    src: url('../fonts/fontello.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/fontello.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/fontello.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/fontello.svg?56990560#fontello') format('svg');
         url('../fonts/fontello.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/fontello.svg#fontello') format('svg');
    src: url('../font/fontello.eot?56990560');
    src: url('../font/fontello.eot?56990560#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/fontello.svg?56990560#fontello') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'fontello';
    src: url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,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') format('woff'),
         url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,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') format('truetype');
  }
  
  [class*="icon-"] {
    font-family: 'fontello';
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 3em;
    speak: none;
  }
  
  .icon-camera:after { content: "\e822"; } 
  .icon-new-student:after { content: "\2699"; } 
  .icon-send-report:after { content: "\27f3"; } 
  .icon-Logout:after { content: "\e724"; } 
  
  * { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box; 
    box-sizing:         border-box; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  html {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    font-size: 100%;    
    background: #092756;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%, rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
    font-size:18px; 
    font-size:1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  
  header {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
  }
  
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DD6C4F;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
  }
  
  a:focus { 
    outline: none;
  }
  
  h1, p, p + p, ul 
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-size: 2rem;    
    line-height: 1.5; 
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .page-wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 80px auto;
  }
  
  .nav {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .nav li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px; /* See: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ */
  }
  
  .nav li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  .nav a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f7f7f7), to(#e7e7e7));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #e7e7e7); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #e7e7e7); 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #e7e7e7); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #e7e7e7); 
    color: #a7a7a7;
    margin: 36px;
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 144px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #aaa, inset 0px 2px 3px #fff;
  }
  
  .nav a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px;
    left: -18px;
    bottom: -18px;
    right: -18px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 48px #ddd;
  }
  
  .nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    background: #f5f5f5;
  }

    .nav a span{
        color:black;
        font-size:10px;
        padding:5px 0 10px 0;
        display:block;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-family:'Josefin Sans';
        letter-spacing:1px;
      }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <title>Welcome!!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="landing_style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="page-wrap">

        <header>
            <h1>Welcome, Admin</h1>
            <p>Dashboard</p>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#" class="icon-camera"><i><span>attendance</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon-new-student"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon-send-report"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="icon-Logout"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
.nav{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

they will be on the same line